# Need help writing query for 3 custom objects in master detail relationship

Tags: soql, query, master-detail, datatable

I'm trying to create a table on Visualforce page like this.

[image]

Each pricelookup's description has it's own activity and purchase info.

Custom parent object - `Pricing_Lookup__c`

Custom child object - `Activity_Lookup__c, Purchase_Lookup__c`

```
public class PackageSummaryController {


    public ApexPages.StandardSetController setConPriceLookUp {
    get {
        if(setConPriceLookUp == null) {
            setConPriceLookUp = new ApexPages.StandardSetController(Database.getQueryLocator( [Select Name, Unit_Price__c, Lookup_Name__c, Description__c, (Select Name, Unit_Price__c From Purchase_Lookup__r),(Select Name, Unit_Price__c From Pricing_Item_Lookup__r )   From Pricing_Lookup__c  ]));
        }
        return setConPriceLookUp;
    }
    set;
}


   public List<Pricing_Lookup__c> getRecords() {
    return ( List<Pricing_Lookup__c>) setConPriceLookUp.getRecords();
}
```

visualforce page.

```
     <table border = "1" cellpadding = "5" cellspacing = "5">
                <tr>
                    <th>Activities</th>
                    <th>Price</th> 
                </tr>
                <apex:repeat value="{!records}" var="record">
                    <tr>
                    <td>{! record.Name }</td>
                    <td>{! record.Unit_Price__c }</td> 
                    </tr>
                </apex:repeat>

                <tr>
                    <th>Purchases</th>
                    <th>Price</th>
                </tr>
                <apex:repeat value="{!records}" var="record">
                    <tr>
                    <td>{! record.Name }</td>
                    <td>{! record.Unit_Price__c }</td> 
                    </tr>
                </apex:repeat>


             </table>
        </table>
```

**How can I distinguish all three name, unit pricing in visualforce page?**

-right now I'm using (record.Name) for pricinglookup's name(mother object)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're actually almost there and you query's fine. Seems like your SOQL query misses the Activity_Lookup__r (if it's not Pricing_Item_Lookup__r) but once you add it, you can use the page markup below.

```
<!-- iterating over Pricing_Lookup__c list -->
<apex:repeat value="{!records}" var="record">
    {! record.Name }
    <table border = "1" cellpadding = "5" cellspacing = "5">
        <tr>
            <th>Activities</th>
            <th>Price</th> 
        </tr>
        <!-- iterating over related Activity_Lookups__r -->
        <apex:repeat value="{!record.Activity_Lookups__r}" var="activity">
            <tr>
            <td>{! activity.Name }</td>
            <td>{! activity.Unit_Price__c }</td> 
            </tr>
        </apex:repeat>
    </table>

    <table border = "1" cellpadding = "5" cellspacing = "5">
        <tr>
            <th>Purchases</th>
            <th>Price</th>
        </tr>
        <!-- iterating over related Purchase_Lookups__r -->
        <apex:repeat value="{!record.Purchase_Lookups__r}" var="purchase">
            <tr>
            <td>{! purchase.Name }</td>
            <td>{! purchase.Unit_Price__c }</td> 
            </tr>
        </apex:repeat>
    </table>
</apex:repeat>
```